# Collection of keys to SharedPreferences

Tags: kotlin

I have collection of keys and a long sheet of keys itself in kotlin. Can I combine it somehow? So that there aren't two sheets?

```
private val allPrefKeys = arrayListOf(
    APP_STYLE,
    STORAGE_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE,
    RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE,
    CAMERA_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE,
    ...
)
//...
private const val APP_STYLE = "APP_STYLE"
    private const val STORAGE_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE =
        "STORAGE_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE"
    private const val RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE =
        "RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE"
    private const val CAMERA_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE =
        "CAMERA_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE"
//...
```

I need a collection to verify that the key from SharedPreferences is contained in the collection.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a [map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-map/):

```
private val allPrefKeys = mapOf(
    APP_STYLE to "APP_STYLE",
    STORAGE_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE to "STORAGE_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE",
    RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE to "RECORD_AUDIO_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE",
    CAMERA_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE to "CAMERA_PERMISSION_DESCRIPTION_DIALOG_STYLE",
)
```

And you can access the right-hand elements of the map with `.values`. For example, if you want to check if the map contains a particular value:

```
val containsKey = allPrefKeys.values.contains("some string")
// OR
val containsKey = allPrefKeys.containsValue("some string") // Does same as above
```

Comment: No, I need to keep the keys as constants too.